# Converting epydoc documentation from html to pdf

Tags: python, documentation-generation, epydoc

I have an online manual in html format for a python module that was generated by `epydoc 3.0.1`, and would like to convert it to a `pdf`. For example, the documentation for `epydoc` itself is available in both [html](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/api/) and [pdf](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/epydoc.pdf). Is there a way to convert documentation maintained in `html` format to `pdf` format?

(In fact, I'm only interested in some segments of the manual rather than all of them, and it would be great if I could choose which html pages I want to add to the pdf).

Comment: If you have access to original doc sources in epydoc, research about direct publishing from this format to pdf. If you have no access to epydoc, the task has nothing to do with epydoc and is about exporting html page to pdf. You shall try to use some virtual printer printing into pdf.

Comment: thanks @JanVlcinsky. I was hoping that there would be some way to convert a html documentation back into the original doc sources, and then publish from the original doc sources to pdf. is there any way you know of doing so?

Comment: I felt this hope from you and must say, it is very unlikely to be done easily.